# Greater Than, Less Than, IF formula + Extra Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote an IF formula as follows...

```
=IF(AB2>=500000,"Platinum",IF(AB2>100000,"Gold",IF(AB2>0,"Silver","")))
```

This works perfectly fine, however I've been given a new caveat and I haven't been able to figure it out.

If Column labeled Sponsor (see below image) has a value, then it should become a "Platinum" tier.

[image]

So pretty much, I'm seeing if it's possible add this additional condition to my existing formula. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=If(LEN(AA2)<> 0,"Platinum",if(AB2>50000,"Platinum .... etc.
```

However, your logic is going to get a bit twisted with the many nested IFs. You might instead consider using a CHOOSE > MATCH structure, thus:

```
=IF(LEN(AA2)<> 0,"Platinum",CHOOSE(MATCH(AB2,{0,100000,500000},1),"Silver","Gold","Platinum"))
```

This formula first checks to see if there's a sponsor, and if there is sets it to "Platinum"; if there isn't it proceeds to the `CHOOSE(MATCH`.

The `MATCH` looks for the largest number in the array (i.e., {0, 100000, 500000}) that is less than or equal to the value in AB2, and returns an index number for where it finds the match. The `CHOOSE` then selects that entry from the list and returns it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch of the explanation! It was very thorough and also explained a different way of approaching this type of formula!

Comment: My pleasure! As a fun bonus, you can also put the lists of values and their matching status into cells for easier maintenance - though in that case, you might want to use an `INDEX` function rather than `CHOOSE`:
`=IF(LEN(A13)<>0,"Platinum",INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MATCH(B13,$F$2:$F$4,1)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can just add an OR() to the IF statement that you already have.

```
=IF(OR(AB2>=500000,AA2<>""),"Platinum",IF(AB2>100000,"Gold",IF(AB2>0,"Silver","")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't think about nesting an OR statement inside of the IF.